# Read NEW "query.yahooapis.com" weather XML

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, xml-namespaces, yahoo-weather-api

I used to use the below to code to retrieve current temperature. But it does not work anymore.

```vb
Set objXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXML.async = "false"
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
objXML.load("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=79105&u=f")
outTEMPer = objXML.selectSingleNode("//item/yweather:condition").Attributes.GetNamedItem("temp").Text
```

New Link is

```vb
objXML.load("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text%3D%22amarillo%2C tx%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
```

But I cannot parse current temp. Have tried

```vb
outTEMPer = objXML.selectSingleNode("//item/yweather:condition").Attributes.GetNamedItem("temp").Text
```

and

```vb
outTEMPer = objXML.getElementsByTagName("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0","condition").getAttribute("temp")
```

XML is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query yahoo:lang="en-us" yahoo:created="2016-03-29T14:50:40Z" yahoo:count="1" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng">
  <!-- total: 19 -->
  <!-- main-1f117507-f23e-11e5-8580-d89d676f9644 -->
  <results>
    <channel>
      <yweather:units temperature="F" speed="mph" pressure="in" distance="mi" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"/>
      <title>Yahoo! Weather - Amarillo, TX, US</title>
      <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2354141/</link>
      <description>Yahoo! Weather for Amarillo, TX, US</description>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <lastBuildDate>Tue, 29 Mar 2016 09:50 AM CDT</lastBuildDate>
      <ttl>60</ttl>
      <yweather:location xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" region=" TX" country="United States" city="Amarillo"/>
      <yweather:wind speed="18" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" direction="175" chill="52"/>
      <yweather:atmosphere pressure="26.13405" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" visibility="10.004077" rising="0" humidity="75"/>
      <yweather:astronomy xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" sunset="8:7 pm" sunrise="7:37 am"/>
      <image>
        <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
        <width>142</width>
        <height>18</height>
        <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
        <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
      </image>
      <item>
        <title>Conditions for Amarillo, TX, US at 09:00 AM CDT</title>
        <geo:lat xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">35.207249</geo:lat>
        <geo:long xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">-101.833893</geo:long>
        <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2354141/</link>
        <pubDate>Tue, 29 Mar 2016 09:00 AM CDT</pubDate>
        <yweather:condition xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" text="Breezy" temp="57" date="Tue, 29 Mar 2016 09:00 AM CDT" code="23"/>
```

The bottom line of the XML code is the one I need.

Thank you Aris. That Worked.

Comment: If it used to work but now doesn't,  try  `Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")` - using the most recent version of the processor sometimes fixes these sort of scripts.

Comment: Use `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` even if the code does work otherwise. `Microsoft.XMLDOM` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't sweat and don't change your previous code. http://**weather.yahooapis.com**/forecastrss is no longer working, but it hasn't disappeared.

It just changed to http://**xml.weather.yahoo.com**/forecastrss
You can change the link in your application to the new address and it will return the data exactly as the former did.
I implemented this calls in an Arduino and it stopped working a few days ago. After searching thru the webz I found they had changed the address. I copied and pasted it and it worked again as new.

*UPDATE:*
As of May 27, 2016, the http://**xml.weather.yahoo.com**/forecastrss URL is no longer working, giving a "Could not connect to server" error.

Answer (score 1):

The XML uses namespaces. Namespaced nodes (and their attributes) can be selected like this:

```vb
uri = "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"
objXML.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ns='" & uri & "'"
outTEMPer = objXML.SelectSingleNode("//item/ns:condition").GetAttribute("temp")
```